# How should I restrict load balanced Web traffic to my Elastic Beanstalk environments?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm trying to configure access to my EB environments, and would like to restrict HTTP access (through the ELB) to certain IP addresses.

I have an out of the box EB app (a bunch, actually, with a few environments each) and would like be able to (a) restrict access to specific sets of IPs while (b) having all traffic come through the ELBs. Critically, I'd like to do this by (c) creating a few groups (e.g an admin SG that allows my IP, and a dev SG that allows a team's IPs, and a public SG that allows all IPs) and applying the groups as needed to each EB environment (often in different combinations to different environments) rather than having to update sources in every environment whenever a team member's IP changes or team membership changes. I'd like to do this without digging around in the network structure and just use the default EB structure.

The default ELB security group allows access from all IPs and is not meant to be edited ("Modifications could impact traffic to future ELBs"), so it seems (naively) there are three approaches I could take:

1. Create a new security group with restricted IP sources for HTTP, and assign it to the ELB instead of the default ELB SG.
2. Create a new security group with restricted IP sources for HTTP, and set it as the source for HTTP in my environment's security group.
3. Leave the default ELB in as is, but restrict the range of allowed source IPs in my EB environment's security group (instead of specifying the ELB's SG as a source).

But (1) seems to require that I also specify the new SG, instead of the default ELB SG, as a source in each of my environments, and (2) seems to require that I assign the new SG to the environment's ELB; while it's not clear in (3) [whether traffic goes through or is filtered by the ELB at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28459479/656912).

The ideal solution for my purposes (at least in theory) would be to have a a small number of security groups for controlling Web access (e.g. one for admin users that lists specific IPs as sources, another for testers that lists a broader range of IPs, and another for public access), and to assign these to environments (as sources for their SG's rules) as appropriate. But this approach (basically 2, above) seems to require that I also assign the groups to each environment's ELB (i.e. I need combine 1 and 2). (This wouldn't be so quite so awkward except that cloned environments seem to [always have default rules](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=601367#601367) for their SGs and default the default SG for their ELBs.)

All this seems too cumbersome and suggests that I'm missing some simpler approach. How should I restrict load balanced Web traffic to my Elastic Beanstalk environments?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to launch your environment inside a VPC so the VPC controls access.

However, if you still just want to use security groups:

1, but assign it to the Beanstalk environment, not the ELB.

You can tell an Elastic Beanstalk Environment to use an already existing Security Group. EB will still create the default Security group, but it will ALSO use your created security group.

You can edit this in the console: Environment -> Configuration -> Instances.
But make sure to add your security group to the comma separated list. Don't remove the one already there.

Comment: So 1 will clone, but I'll still get the default ELB group back when I clone, and can just remove it if I want 1's rules only? (I think everything is in a VPC already.)

Comment: Yes. The clone will create another default security group, and also apply the one you created.

Comment: And I just leave everything else as is: the ELB keeps its default, and I don't delete the EB's default? I just *add* my SG to the EB environment?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to set up: I have an out of the box EB app (a bunch, actually, with a few environments each) and would like be able to (a) restrict access to specific sets of IPs while (b) having all traffic come through the ELBs. Critically, I'd like to do this by (c) creating a few groups (e.g an admin SG that allows my IP, and a dev SG that allows a team's IPs, and a public SG that allows all IPs) and applying the groups as needed to each EB environment rather than having to update sources in every environs whenever a team member's IP changes or team membership changes.

Comment: Should work in theory. Go try it out and see if you have success.

Comment: Doesn't work: (i) I have the default SG signed to the ELB, (ii) that group as a source for HTTP in my EB environment's default SG (basically I leave that as is by default), and the only change I've made from the out-of-the-box EB configuration is to (iii) add my SG to the EB environment. I have access, but so do all IPs.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to do it the normal way, using your vpc. Here's somewhere to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222154/restrict-http-access-to-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: I can get it working by *replacing* the ELB's SG and the source for my EB environment's SG with my own SG (that makes sense). But the question is whether that's necessary (and why it doesn't clone, once done). Using the VPC means it applies to all my applications at once, right; not by environment; or does it mean I now need to poke around in my network structure (not at all the EB level of abstraction)? Restricting Web access to specific IP addresses seems like it ought to be easier than this (isn't that what SGs are for?)

Comment: Or do I need to create a different VPC for each environment (and ACLs to go with it)?

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need to do is go to the EC2 Security Groups and create your security groups and access permissions.

Once you have setup those security groups head on over to your Elastic Beanstalk Environment and select **Configuration** and then **Instances**. You will see a field called EC2 Security Groups under the Server section; and the names of the security groups (comma separated) that you created previously.

**Note:** Leave the security group that has already been defined.
  **Note:** The default security group allows all traffic from the ELB

[image]

Comment: That's the solution suggested in a comment by @NickHumrich; but it doesn't work. That continues to allow all traffic from all IPs. The only thing that seems to work (after trying nearly every permutation, but this was my first guess) is — and this makes sense —to replace the default SG assigned to the ELB, both at the ELB and as the inbound source for the EB environment's SG's rule. Again, that makes perfect sense; it just seemed to me like a lot of steps and a bit frustrating that it's not cloned.

Comment: I've [edited the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28459626/revisions) (from the comments below) to elaborate on what I'm trying to achieve. And again: I've discovered that I can accomplish this with the method described in the comment above; I just now wonder if it is to complex approach (though the more I live with it, the more it seems manageable — provided there's nothing *wrong* with it).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius you're first comment helped me out alot, thank you. I changed the inbound setting on the SG for the load balancer to only accept traffic from the SG within my VPC and it successfully blocks outside Ips.