# How to restrict client access to elastic beanstalk app?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lumen

What is the difference between a aws security group and aws acl? I have a Lumen microservice I set up using elastic beanstalk with autoscaling and load balancing (using the "getting started" guide). The service should only be accessible from certain ip addresses. I have not understood the solutions suggested so far. Some of them suggested using ACL in a vpc while others suggested using a security group.

Note:-

1) I'm still learning about elastic beanstalk. But I have noticed that when setting up with elastic beanstalk, the ec2 instance is automatically put in a vpc. Don't know if this helps.

2) Is there something similar to aws s3 ip address restriction like in this https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjau8uG1fHSAhUKObwKHSFvAWwQygQIIDAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2FAmazonS3%2Flatest%2Fdev%2Fexample-bucket-policies.html%23example-bucket-policies-use-case-3&usg=AFQjCNHnwi9tEtzDoPSQ6LjruQjDg1d5Tw

Comment: Security Group will do exactly what you are describing.

Comment: @Mark B Then what about the content here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222154/restrict-http-access-to-elastic-beanstalk Why not use an ACL?

Comment: Network ACL are lower level and stateless. Security Groups are generally preferred over ACL. You can accomplish your requirement with either, but I recommend you focus on Security Groups for now, especially since you are new to AWS.

Comment: Network ACL will provide you subnet level access control while Security Groups can be more granular (Basically a firewall), even for per instance or per load balancer. For your case you can add a rule in load balancers security group to allow inbound connections from only your ip address

Comment: Hi @Ashan, I added my ip address as the source entry of the security group associated with the load balancer. But it ended up blocking from my ip address. Any solutions?

Comment: Check the following things. ELB has a public url. Instances are placed in public subnet or if in private subnets there should be corresponding public subnets in Availability zones. Also check ec2 instances security groups whether they allows inbound from ELB